# Which connector is this three connections inline XS 20 marking

Tags: connector, wiring, power-connector, connect

I can't find the connector type of this part found on alibaba for which I need its mate.

I have it in front to me. body is 300mil width and about 200mil thick.
Pin spacing 2.5mm (NOT 100mil!!!!)

There is a marking of XS 20 on the side of the connector.

On trace of information on product page. No datasheet on alibaba.
https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Diesel-fuel-flow-sensor-oval-gear_60419553239.html

Feels pretty standard, but I can't figure out which one it is.

[image: Connector of Aichi OF05ZAT flow sensor]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a [JST SMP series](https://www.jst-mfg.com/product/pdf/eng/eSM.pdf), specifically a SMP-03V-BC.

Comment: It is! Do you know this from experience or are there methods that make one get the type like a determination process for plants? (that would be fun if it doesnt exist)

Comment: I go on Digikey and select what I think is the best category - in this case rectangular connector housings - then select the number of pins, number of rows, and pitch (0.98"/2.5mm).  That usually narrows it down to a few pages and from there it only takes a minute to scroll through and look at the pictures.