# How can I identify the names of different connectors?

Tags: identification, connector

Numerous questions exist that seek to identify a name for a particular connector.

How can I go about learning these names, or self-identifying a particular connector using web resources?

Comment: Spend a lot of time thumbing through the catalog of your favorite distributor page-by-page. (just kidding, no more paper catalogs available for this)

Comment: @ThePhoton thumbing? are you referring to a new kind of touchscreen I have never heard about? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you must understand that, by my count, only 30 % of industry-standard connectors have a name that is widely accepted by the industry (e.g, "pin-and-socket"). About 10 % have "street names" (e.g., "DuPont") that have no basis on what manufacturers call them. The rest have no name, which is why I took the liberty to coin terms for many of them (e.g., "[single-wall connectors](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22single-wall+wire-to-board+connectors%22)").

The proprietary connectors have names assigned to them by their manufacturers (e.g., "Sure-Lok"), consortia (e.g., "USB-C"), or standards organizations (e.g., "BNC").

Please allow me to offer you my [Identicon utility](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN) that lists the names of all connectors, whether official, street name, or coined by me.

Answer (score 0):

@[vir](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/260734/vir) [comments](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/623690/which-connector-is-this-three-connections-inline-xs-20-marking#comment1647702_623693):

> I go on Digikey and select what I think is the best category - in this case rectangular connector housings - then select the number of pins, number of rows, and pitch (0.98"/2.5mm). That usually narrows it down to a few pages and from there it only takes a minute to scroll through and look at the pictures.

(note; This answer was by @vir in a comment to another question. I thought it would be useful as a full question/answer.  @vir, if you wish to post this as an answer I will delete this answer in favor of yours.)

Comment: No, you're fine.  I'll just add that Davide Andrea has a good utility to identify connectors here: https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN

Comment: @vir Thank you for posting that link.